# How detect current DVD running in disk rive using batch code

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch code that lists the letter of installed drive disk and saves it to drive.txt, and this is working perfect.

My problem is that when PC has more one disk drive, my code will not get the letter of the disk drive which is currently playing a DVD/CD.
I want to get the letter of the drive which is currently playing a DVD/CD.

How can I do it?

My current code is:

```
(for /f "skip=1" %%d IN ('wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=5 get deviceid') DO echo/%%d )>drives.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean with "currently running"? Active I/O? Inserted Media?

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly adapted version of my answer to your last question. It looks for CD/DVD-drives and checks, if there is a valid disc inserted.

As I know, there is no possibilty to check if a movie is currently played from this drive.

```
(for /f  %%d IN ('wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=5 get deviceid^|findstr :') DO dir %%d >nul 2>1 && (echo %%d ready) || (echo %%d no disc))>disc.txt
```

Comment: yes but, I dont want disk.txt to save with path just I need with letter only. how can I do?